# Redis Elasticache sub milli second response time?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS Redis Elasticache is advertised as being sub-millisecond. But in any meaningful use case there will be a network latency calling the elasticache service, so at best in the 10s of milliseconds…is this correct ? Redis Elasticache always has to be called over the network, not running on the same server as the application server correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct. Elasticache provides sub millisecond response times, but you will always have network delays. If your application is hosted on EC2 in the same region then latency will be sub millisecond at the application end. However, the further away you place your application from the elasticache cluster the greater latency you will receive, you cannot defy the laws of physics.

Here is a good guide to reducing latencies for Elasticache for Redis:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elasticache-redis-correct-high-latency/

Comment: "If your application is hosted on EC2 in the same region then latency will be sub millisecond at the application end." 

Is this statement really true ? That network latencies in the same region are sub-millisecond ? Do you have a reference ?

Comment: You need to test your specific network. To isolate network latency between the client and cluster nodes, use TCP traceroute or mtr tests from the application environment. Or, use a debugging tool such as the AWSSupport-SetupIPMonitoringFromVPC AWS Systems Manager document (SSM document) to test connections from the client subnet.